# What does mean $\mathrm{conv}\{\{+1, -1\}^d\}$

Tags: vectors, polytopes, convex-hulls

What does mean $\mathrm{conv}\{e_1 , -e_l , \ldots , e_d , -e_d\}$ and $\mathrm{conv}\{\{+1, -1\}^d\}.$

I could not understand, need a simple explanation.

Comment: Not sure from the amount of info you gave us, but this might be talking about "convex hull" or "convex polytope", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: Likely means the convex hull of a set, the smallest convex set containing the members.

Comment: how vectors are forming, I need a visual sample.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the case $d=3$.

The set $\{\{+1, -1\}^d\}$ is the set of all triples (there are $2^3=8$ of them)

$$\{(-1,-1,-1), (-1,-1,1), (-1,1,-1), \cdots (1,1,1) \}$$

i.e., the vertices of a cube.

More generally, $\{+1, -1\}^d$ is the set of vertices of a hypercube in $\mathbb{R^d}$.

As a consequence:

$$\mathrm{conv}\{\{+1, -1\}^d\}$$ is the "solid hypercube" in $\mathbb{R}^d$.